# Google sheets: How do I return a text value based on a column matching an entire range?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need help returning a text value "WIP" based on column A matching an entire range.

The range has digits which users will input that match column A but cells will have more than 1 digit which will be seperated by a comma.

I'm not clear on how to do this so i'm stuck somewhere with:

Sumproduct, isnumber, and match yet i'm struggling how to yield a result.

Could you please help?

Thanks a lot!

Spreadsheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XcIql3ZMymqipZsGUyBk3_ze6LMzjQtHTF-ylGDIT_A/edit#gid=0

Output highlighted in yellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(Isnumber(MATCH(A9:A38,FLATTEN(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(LEN(G8:M18),G8:M18,)),",")),0)),"WIP",))
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly it, @basic ! That's amazing! How do i get as good as you?